# Calulating the Big O complexity of my program

Tags: java, big-o

My program prints all the permutations of a word that has double letters
For example
In the word 'Helloo'

The result would be:
[heloo, helo, hello, helloo]

```
private List<String> doubleLetterPermute(String start, String ending, List<String> possibleWords) {
    String prev = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < ending.length(); i++) {
        String letter = String.valueOf(ending.charAt(i));
        // its a double letter
        if (letter.equals(prev)) {
            doubleLetterPermute(start + ending.substring(0, i), ending.substring(i + 1), possibleWords);
            doubleLetterPermute(start + ending.substring(0, i + 1), ending.substring(i + 1), possibleWords);
        }
        prev = letter;
    }
    possibleWords.add(start + ending);
    return possibleWords;
}
```

I am not sure how to calculate the complexity when recursive functions come in.
It loops n times, where n is the number of characters in a word, O(n), but I am splitting the word on each occurrence of a double letter so how does that show in the big O notation?

Comment: Big-O for permutation is typically O(n!), see [this page](http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2010/12/07/comp-sci-101-big-o-notation/) for a reference

Answer (score 1):

In order to calculate your complexity, you need to look at the worst and best cases.

At best, you would have a word of length N with no double letters, let's say "**abcde**". Your complexity would be O(n) because you have only one loop of size N.

At worst, you would have a word of length N with the same letter, let's say "**aaaaa**". In this case, you have a loop of size N, which contains 2 loops of size (N - i). So, the complexity would be O(2(n-i)*n), or O(n^2).

Comment: Thanks Kimko. When giving the final Big O result, do you take the worst or best case?

Comment: @Decrypter on Big O analysis you **always** take the worst case. In this case, it looks like O(2^n) time analysis.